# Need excel formula to compare cell contents with array of partial strings with special characters and return result in next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-matching

I have a column of html links, e.g.,

```
    Sheet 1, Column A:
     a href="http://junk.com">
     a href="http://example.com">
     a href='/relative-link/' target=''>
```

I want to compare a list of substrings in A:A on another sheet and return the value in B:B. 
So for example, my list on another sheet may be:

```
    Sheet2:
    Column A        Column B
    example.com      mine
    href='/         relative
    href="http      external
```

So I would need a formula that for the column of html links would return:

```
    Sheet1:
     Column A                                Column B (formula)
     a href="http://junk.com">               external
     a href="http://example.com">            mine
     a href='/relative-link/' target=''>     relative
```

Any ideas? I know how to use INDEX/MATCH for exact matches, but not sure how to do it with a partial substring match. Also, I don't know if the special characters in some of the substrings will require anything different than a single alphanumerical word.

Many thanks.

Comment: For older Excel version with no `AGGREGATE` function, inspired by @Gary'sStudent post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37683342/4388883), you can try this formula: `=VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(99^99,SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,A1),Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3),Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0)`.  However, this string `href="http` also shows in `a href="http://example.com">` and therefore, the result is not ideal.  I couldn't find a way to solve this but maybe @Gary'sStudent will show up and further assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,A1))),1))
```

This will return the first match on sheet 2, so put that list in order of priority.

[image]